Unwanted indent with bidi and tcolorbox packages
Note: Everything below is compiled with XeLaTeX.
I'm trying to develop pullout boxes for a textbook using the tcolorbox package. Sometimes these boxes will contain multiple paragraphs, for which I want the usual parskip/parindent options I've set for the rest of the book. The book also contains Arabic and Persian scripts, so calling polyglossia also loads the bidi package. However, using tcolorbox, bidi, and parbox=false all at once introduces an unwanted space before the first line.
The MWE below calls the bidi package directly in an attempt to isolate the problem, but it works the same using polyglossia and \setotherlanguages{arabic,persian}. This code produces the following result:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{bidi}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[parbox=false]
\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}


Unloading bidi fixes the problem immediately (as does using parbox=true).
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
% \usepackage{bidi}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[parbox=false]
\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}


I don't expect to use Arabic/Persian script within the tcolorboxes themselves, only in other parts of the book. But even just loading both packages together (in either order) produces the error. Is there any way to fix this unwanted interaction?
Edit: The problem seems to be with Overleaf; no unwanted space appears when I compile it locally. Not sure why that happens but I can always compile the end result locally so I guess this is resolved.

Welcome to TeX.SE!

I can't reproduce your issue. Is your distribution up-to-date?

The work is being done in Overleaf, I should have specified. I tried compiling it offline and I don't get the issue anymore---so that might be it! Maybe it will be better to download the whole project and compile it locally after edits are done.
